# PostgreSQL and PostGIS install on RHEL server

Tags: postgis, postgresql, linux, red-hat

I am trying to install both PostgreSQL and the PostGIS extension onto my RedHat Linux server. I have been able to install PostgreSQL with the yum installation however I cannot install PostGIS this way and have come across several issues. I need to have both installed so I can reach the information from a webmap I'm trying to create.

Comment: what issues have you had?

Comment: are you using this official guide? http://www.postgresonline.com/journal/archives/362-An-almost-idiots-guide-to-install-PostgreSQL-9.5,-PostGIS-2.2-and-pgRouting-2.1.0-with-Yum.html

Comment: Error: Package: gdal-libs-1.11.4-12.rhel7.x86_64 (pgdg10)
           Requires: libarmadillo.so.8()(64bit)
The above is my specific issue

Comment: I have been using the official guide thank you, I have used the 9.4 version however and have made it up to the sudo yum install postgis2_95 step (I replaced the 95 with 94)

Comment: Maybe take a look at this thread: [link](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/postgis-users/Yi2LpJW3xXo) If you don't need anything specific, the simpliest way is to use ready-to-use docker. Install docker on your server and just do, for example: `sudo docker run --name "postgis" -p 5432:5432 -d -t kartoza/postgis`. This would launch it and make it accessible on the 5432 port from the exterior.

Comment: Thank you! both of those links were very helpful and I've figured it out. I was missing some dependencies.